Need to Develop React native app using Sitecore 10.1 headless architecture
I need to develop a mobile app using Sitecore 10.1 headless architecture. Please suggest on this. Should we go with React Native and if yes then please share if any reference available.

It's experimental, not supported, and probably not recommended, but if you want to see an example of how to use React Native with the Sitecore JSS APIs, you can look at the React Native SDK for JSS: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/latest/sitecore-headless-development/sitecore-javascript-rendering-sdk--jss--for-react-native.html
Should you go with React Native? You can, but just know that you won't be able to get product support on the React Native SDK itself. You'll need to be ready to support this on your own, so make sure your team really knows React Native already.
